# facing issue while getting size of web element into a integer variable

Tags: java

> Type mismatch:can not convert from dimension to int.

```
int sizeOfServiceInstanceRow = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr")).getSize();
```

We should size of web element in `sizeOfServiceInstanceRow` variable.

Comment: What datatype is returned from getSize()?

Answer (score 0):

From selenium docs `getSize` returns a `Dimension` object(which contains height and width properties), you can't directly cast it to an `int` type.

If you are interested in getting the height and width of the element, then you can do as below.

```
Dimension elemDimension = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr")).getSize();
int height  = elemDimension.getHeight();
int width   = elemDimension.getWidth();
```

refer docs 
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getSize--

Comment: I have done following changes:                                                   List<WebElement> serviceInstanceCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr"));
  driver.getAssertionService().addAssertionLog("Service instance count is"+serviceInstanceCount.size(), MessageTypes.Info);                                                                         And imported required packages.